# Not able to edit or add in the HTML Code part PageBuilder

Tags: admin, magento2.3.1, page-builder

I used the FAQ extension in Magento 2.2 EE. But we have migrated to 2.3. I am not able to edit or add in the HTML Code part. All the other fields are working. How to edit this.

Comment: i am facing the same issue, how you solved it? Any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add an HTML element in Page Builder or you can use the older version of TinyMCE which you can turn on in

Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Content Management -> WYSIWIG Options